# Put energy into void

Tags: energy, universe

what happens when you drop matter or energy of any type into the void , by void I mean a space of absolute emptiness with nothing more than darkness  and total absence of every kind of energy , basically popping energy into existence

From my basic knowledge of physics my only theory is that all the energy will spread equally into the void  creating an universe made of finite energy that one day all the energy spread around will no more be able to support any work causing the death of the universe  forever and transforming it into nothingness again

Comment: Be careful about down votes here. I expect Aten is making a guess as to what happens, rather than proposing a personal theory. Aten, a hint. Personal theories get down voted here. This site has its quirks.

Comment: Define "void". Nothing particular happens when you drop matter into vacuum, but no other state of "void" is well-defined in physics.

Comment: by void i mean an not isolated , limitless absolute emptiness

Comment: Please send me a sample of "limitless, absolute emptiness" and I will drop some matter into it. I will record what happens and publish the data.

Answer (score 1):

One way to send energy off is to shine a flashlight upwards. The beam will go until it hits something. That may be years for the portion of the beam that happens to be aimed exactly toward a star or other object.

It turns out that a lot of the beam will go between stars. Stars and such are really spread out. That part of the beam will keep going. Nothing much happens to it while it travels. The wavelength will slowly increase due to expansion of the universe.

There is a huge amount of light left over from the big bang that hasn't yet hit anything yet. The wavelength of that light has grown so much that it is now in the microwave region - much larger than visible light.